# File not showing in C:\ but it is there

Tags: windows-explorer

I saved a file as .jpg on my C:\ in windows 10.  I then went to Windows Explorer to move it to another directory but it is not there.  I checked for hidden files in cmd and nothing.  However in Photoshop I can click on File-> Open in the C:\ and it is there.  Right clicking on properties Hidden is not checked.   I can open it in Photoshop and save it to a subdirectory of c: and it is there.

Why does it not show in File Explorer but it does in Photoshop?

Comment: you also need to enable *show protected system files*

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop I created a second file with a different name.  Still can't see it.
In Photoshop, I right clicked on one of the files, then selected Create Shortcut.  It asked if I wanted to place it on the desktop and I said yes.

I clicked on the shortcut and it opened it in Photos.  File Info said 
Folder Path C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\VirtualStore

Both files were there in that directory.

One site said about Virtual Store:
When a virtualized program attempts to write to a protected location such as Program Files, Windows will intercept the access denied response and redirect the write to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VirtualStore, which is a hidden folder.

When a virtualized program attempts to read from a protected location, Windows will first check for a copy of the file in VirtualStore. If it finds it, it will use that copy. Otherwise it will attempt to read from the original file.

So it is protecting c root and sending files there but the virtualized app knows where to look.

Comment: cool I didn't knew that.